# How to share/pin message with Image in Pinterest through my Android application

Tags: android, android-intent, pinterest, socialshare, pin-it-sdk

I am trying to integrate Pinterest to my android application and to pin/share message with image.But I am not getting any way to do this.
I downloaded the Pinterest SDK and added the jar file in my project.

Following is my code snnipet.

```
PinIt pinIt = new PinIt();
    PinIt.setPartnerId("My ID");
    pinIt.setUrl("http://placekitten.com/400/300");
    pinIt.setImageUrl(m_cObjSocialTable.getPinterestImagePath());
    pinIt.setDescription(pMessage);
    pinIt.setListener(new PinItListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(boolean completed) {
            super.onComplete(completed);
            if (completed) {
                System.out.println("Pinit complete");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onException(Exception e) {
            super.onException(e);
            System.out.println("Pinit Exception");
        }
    });
    pinIt.doPinIt(this);
```

But it is not posting, in onComplete() we are getting false.
Please help me on it

Thanks & Regards
Tiru

Comment: Can you please mention the name of the jar to be added, as I am getting *cannot resolve symbol `'PinIt'`*

Answer (score 5):

```
 IntentBuilder lIntentBuilder = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this); 
Uri lPictureUri = null;
lPictureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File("mnt/sdcard/1.jpg"));
lIntentBuilder.setStream(lPictureUri);
String lType = null != lPictureUri ? "image/jpeg" : "text/plain";
lIntentBuilder.setType(lType);
lIntentBuilder.setText("My Description");
Intent shareIntent = lIntentBuilder.getIntent().setPackage("com.pinterest");
shareIntent.putExtra("com.pinterest.EXTRA_DESCRIPTION", "Messagessssssssss");
startActivity(shareIntent)
```

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: With the actual PinIt SDK, the setDescription method is working correctly.

Unfortunately, there is not way. I mean, it should work with setDescription() but is not. That seems to be a bug on the pinterest SDK.

Comment: I have done in a different way.But in this case user has to install the Pinterest app in his/her device.

Comment: How to pinit share without application?? @hmartinezd

Comment: @Tripaty : Can you please share your method?
We are not able to get whether the pin is actually shared or canceled...
Is there any other method to retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

**Oncreate method :**

```
PinItButton.setPartnerId("*******"); // required

PinItButton.setDebugMode(true); // optional
```

**onclick event:**

```
PinIt pinIt = new PinIt();
pinIt.setUrl(site url);
pinIt.setImageUrl(Image url);
pinIt.setDescription(description);
pinIt.setListener(new PinItListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
        }
        @Override
        public void onComplete(boolean completed) {
            super.onComplete(completed);
            if (completed) {
                System.out.println("Pinit complete");
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onException(Exception e) {
            super.onException(e);
            System.out.println("Pinit Exception");
        }
    });
pinIt.doPinIt(this);
```

i think its work fine.

Comment: crashing :: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.pinterest.pinit.PinItButton